# Can the Flash Bomb upgrade pop leads?

Tags: bloons-td-5

The Ninja Monkey's 0-3 upgrade has a flash bomb. Can it pop leads? It is a bomb right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can.  It is a bomb for the purpose of popping leads.

Source:  http://bloons.wikia.com/wiki/Flash_Bomb

Comment: Can confirm that this answer is correct.

Comment: I'd advise just grabbing a 0-1 (0-2 if stealth leads) Apprentice and setting it to strong. It's much cheaper and upgraded to 2-2 can pop a lot of leads at once. It doesn't stun though.

Comment: @Gnarly404 Cool, thanks for the tip!